# Tukey HSD Post Hoc test with the Anova() Command (Car-package)

Tags: r, anova, tukey-hsd-test

I am trying to do a Tukey-Test with the `Anova()` command from the car-package. I am using `Anova()` because I have an unbalanced Dataset. A statistic professor from my Uni told me `Anova()` would solve this problem. However he didn't tell me, how one could do a Tukey Test with it afterwards.

`Tukey.HSD` from R; `HST.Test` from agricola and emmeans all don't seem to work. I already did some research and found the post below, which also doesn't provide an answer.

I am relatively new to R, so I might've missed something.

Below you see the two factorial code. I am trying to do a Tukey test for A and C. You can see how the significance changes depending on what factor comes first. The significance stays the same when using Anova from the car-package. The significance interaction A:C seems to stay the same with and with out an unbalanced Dataset. Only small difference is due to `lm()` oder `aov()`. So I just did the Tukey-test for it with an unbalanced dataset.

So is it possible to do a Tukey-test with A`nova()`? If so, how?

```
data_NIRS$dv<-data_NIRS$Sinapine
data_NIRS$dv<-data_NIRS$Sinapine
> m1 <-aov(data_NIRS$dv~data_NIRS$A*data_NIRS$C)
> m2 <-aov(data_NIRS$dv~data_NIRS$C*data_NIRS$A)
> summary(m1)
                         Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value   Pr(>F)    
data_NIRS$A               2  23.14  11.570   23.92 6.30e-10 ***
data_NIRS$C               2  11.04   5.522   11.42 2.16e-05 ***
data_NIRS$A:data_NIRS$C   4   3.87   0.967    2.00   0.0965 .  
Residuals               178  86.10   0.484                     
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
> summary(m2)
                         Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value   Pr(>F)    
data_NIRS$C               2  17.69   8.846   18.29 5.98e-08 ***
data_NIRS$A               2  16.49   8.246   17.05 1.68e-07 ***
data_NIRS$C:data_NIRS$A   4   3.87   0.967    2.00   0.0965 .  
Residuals               178  86.10   0.484                     
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
> m3 <-lm(data_NIRS$dv~data_NIRS$A*data_NIRS$C)
> m4 <-lm(data_NIRS$dv~data_NIRS$C*data_NIRS$A)
> anova(m3)
Analysis of Variance Table

Response: data_NIRS$dv
                     Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value    Pr(>F)    
data_NIRS$A               2 23.141 11.5704 23.9196 6.299e-10 ***
data_NIRS$C               2 11.045  5.5223 11.4163 2.163e-05 ***
data_NIRS$A:data_NIRS$C   4  3.870  0.9675  2.0001   0.09647 .  
Residuals               178 86.102  0.4837                      
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
> anova(m4)
Analysis of Variance Table

Response: data_NIRS$dv
                     Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value    Pr(>F)    
data_NIRS$C               2 17.693  8.8464 18.2883 5.978e-08 ***
data_NIRS$A               2 16.493  8.2463 17.0476 1.683e-07 ***
data_NIRS$C:data_NIRS$A   4  3.870  0.9675  2.0001   0.09647 .  
Residuals               178 86.102  0.4837                      
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
> Anova(m3)
Anova Table (Type II tests)

Response: data_NIRS$dv
                    Sum Sq  Df F value    Pr(>F)    
data_NIRS$A             16.493   2 17.0476 1.683e-07 ***
data_NIRS$C             11.045   2 11.4163 2.163e-05 ***
data_NIRS$A:data_NIRS$C  3.870   4  2.0001   0.09647 .  
Residuals               86.102 178                      
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
> Anova(m4)
Anova Table (Type II tests)

Response: data_NIRS$dv
                    Sum Sq  Df F value    Pr(>F)    
data_NIRS$C             11.045   2 11.4163 2.163e-05 ***
data_NIRS$A             16.493   2 17.0476 1.683e-07 ***
data_NIRS$C:data_NIRS$A  3.870   4  2.0001   0.09647 .  
Residuals               86.102 178                      
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
>
```

Relevant SO thread: [How to do a Tukey HSD test with the Anova command (car package)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7732459/how-to-do-a-tukey-hsd-test-with-the-anova-command-car-package)

Comment: In what way does *emmeans* not work ?

Comment: The statistic professor wrote this line of code befor we had the problem with the unbalanced dataset. 
`lsm.A<-emmeans(m2, pairwise~A,adjust="Tukey", type="response",infer=TRUE);lsm.A
est.A<-lsm.A$emmeans
contr.A<-lsm.A$contrasts
cld.A<-as.data.frame(cld(est.A,
                         alpha=0.05,
                         Letters=letters,     
                         adjust="tukey")   )`

Comment: @Sal Mangiafico 
I get the following:
Error in (function (object, at, cov.reduce = mean, cov.keep = get_emm_option("cov.keep"),  : 
  Can't handle an object of class  “anova” 
 Use help("models", package = "emmeans") for information on supported models.

Comment: Run emmeans on the model, not on the anova result.

Answer (score 1):

As to the use of *emmeans* here, this is really a programming question.  The code just needs to be updated a little:

```
A = rep(c("I","II","III"), each=5)
Y = c(1,2,3,4,5,3,4,5,6,7,9,10,11,12,13)
m1 = lm(Y~A)

library(emmeans)

lsm.A<-emmeans(m1, ~A) 
summary(lsm.A, type="response",infer=TRUE)
pairs(lsm.A)

library(multcomp)
cld(lsm.A,alpha=0.05,Letters=letters)
```

EDIT:  model name changed from *m2* to *m1* to avoid confusion with the example in the comments.

Comment: Hey, could you explain the function of your first 2 lines?  Would I have to adjust them to my dataset?. Sorry... R is new to me.

Comment: Yes, the first two lines just make up some toy data so the example can be run as is.  So, yes, instead you would use your actual data, loaded in whatever method you want (*read.table*, *read.csv*, etc.)

Comment: Awesome thanks! I will try it out.

Comment: I still get the same error.

`data_NIRS$dv<-data_NIRS$Sinapine

m1 <-lm(data_NIRS$dv~data_NIRS$A*data_NIRS$C)

m2<-Anova(m1)

A=data_NIRS$A

lsm.A<-emmeans(m2, ~A) 

summary(lsm.A, type="response",infer=TRUE)

pairs(lsm.A)`

Comment: I also dont know how to make the comments here more spaced out :D

Comment: Yes, you don't run *emmeans* on the *Anova* object, you run it on the model object.  (In your case on *m1*, not on *m2*). The model is specified with the *lm()* function.  After that, what analysis you do with e.g. *Anova()*, *anova()*, or *lrtest(*) is a different matter.

Comment: But I am trying to run it on the Anova object due to the unbalanced dataset. Or is the tukey Test not influenced by the unbalanced dataset?

Comment: *emmeans* addresses the model object.  Functions like *anova()* and *Anova()* also address the model object.  If you will, they do two different things with the same kind of object. *emmeans* shouldn't be bothered by the unbalanced design.   It's a good approach in the case of unbalanced design, assuming the model is an appropriate one.

Comment: Okey that makes sense! Thank you very much :)